# How do I find duplicate records in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 60k records, I need to find records which are duplicates based on column `Crime ID`, so far I found out this:

```
SELECT * FROM crimedata GROUP BY `Crime ID` HAVING COUNT(`Crime ID`) > 1
```

This query returns how many times particular `Crime ID` occurred. As most of `Crime ID` appered twice it worked, but I have also 10k of records where `Crime ID` is empty(its not null) and that query can't distinguish that. I need a query that would return every `Crime ID` that is duplicate and would leave one as the unique first.

```
Crime ID | column2 | column3 |
------------------------------
abc            a        b        1
abc            a        a        2
a              b        b        3
b              b        b        4
a              a        a        5
b              a        a        6
abc            b        a        7
```

From this example query would return 2, 5, 6, 7 record.

Comment: Try adding where condition as column != ''

Comment: are you asking about database or table?

Comment: sorry you are right, this is a table

Comment: Do you want _all_ the records with matches or just the _extra_ records, exclusive of some _original_ record?

Comment: It's also not clear what you're using to class a row as _duplicate_. You say where the `column` is the same but then go on to say that all the empty `column` values are not duplicates. That's very confusing

Comment: Row is a duplicate if there is any other row with same value in same column in the table, so obviously empty values are duplicates.

Comment: This is not really clear.  You need to post your query with a sample of the result you are getting accompanied by the result you want.  Please don't post images

Comment: _"obviously empty values are duplicates"_ <- but you want to see them all, not grouped? Is that correct? If so, what columns do you want to see? Like @billynoah said, add some examples of what you'd like the result to be

Comment: Allright, after thinking about that it actually doesn't make sense, now I get, I have asked too fast, anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah i wanted them all separately as I want to export them to a text file in my Java program. Program export value of every column so I thought that it also should treat every empty value of this column as separate duplicate record.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have edited first post, i hope that this explanation is better.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking. What happened to the _empty_ `Crime ID` records in your example? What distinguishes a record as being a duplicate vs the _original_ or _"unique first"_?

Comment: Record is duplicate if Crime ID in this record is used in another record appeared earlier. And yeah there are still empty Crime ID values. Original Crime ID is the one which appeared first in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to get what I wanted.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    `column1`, 
    `column2`, 
    `column3`,
HAVING COUNT(`column1`) > 1
    AND COUNT(`column2`) > 1
    AND COUNT(`column3`) > 1
```

This returns me every record which appear more than once in database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check null, then it will give you desired output. Below query was tested on MSSQL.

Which database are you using? If you understand this then change it so it works on your server else tell us.

I tried to convert the query to MySQL, please check.

```
SELECT `Crime ID` ,COUNT(NULLIF(`Crime ID`,'')) FROM crimedata GROUP BY `Crime ID` HAVING COUNT(NULLIF(`Crime ID`,''))  > 1
```

Comment: Value is not actaully null its just empty nothing typed in there.

Comment: hope so it will work. SELECT `Crime ID` ,COUNT(case `Crime ID` when '' then 'empty'else `Crime ID` end) FROM crimedata GROUP BY `Crime ID` HAVING COUNT(case `Crime ID` when '' then 'empty'else `Crime ID` end)  > 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use rank.

```
SELECT* from (
    SELECT `Crime ID`, `column 2`, `column 3`, Rank() over (partition by CrimeID order by `Crime ID`) as myrank
    FROM crimedata
) rankedlist
WHERE myrank = 1
```

If you want to select the duplicate records and ignore the originals, you can select `WHERE myrank > 1`

If you order by something meaningful, like the filing date (if you keep track of it), you will be able to select the entry which was there before others.

Selecting the duplicate records will let you aggregate data from them and merge them into the original record, if this is your intent.

Comment: It could be working but my database is MySQL and as I googled MySQL doesn't have Rank() function.